# Error on closing an empty iTextSharp document

Tags: c#, pdf, merge, itext

I am successfully merging PDF documents; now as I'm trying to implement the error handling in case no PDF document has been selected, it throws an error when closing the document: **The document has no pages**
In case no PDF document has been added in the "foreach" - loop, I still need to close the document!? Or not? If you open an object then it has do be closed at some point. So how to I escape correctly in case no page had been added?

```
        private void MergePDFs()
    {
        DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
        DataView view = (DataView)SourceCertCockpit.Select(args);

        System.Data.DataTable table = view.ToTable();
        List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();

        iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, Response.OutputStream);
        document.Open();

        int index = 0;
        foreach (DataRow myRow in table.Rows)
        {
            if (ListadoCertificadosCockpit.Rows[index].Cells[14].Text == "0")
            {
                PdfReader Reader = new PdfReader(Convert.ToString(myRow[0]));
                Chapter Chapter = new Chapter(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(myRow[1])), 0);
                Chapter.NumberDepth = 0;
                iTextSharp.text.Section Section = Chapter.AddSection(Convert.ToString(myRow[10]), 0);
                Section.NumberDepth = 0;
                iTextSharp.text.Section SubSection = Section.AddSection(Convert.ToString(myRow[7]), 0);
                SubSection.NumberDepth = 0;
                document.Add(Chapter);
                readerList.Add(Reader);
                for (int i = 1; i <= Reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(Reader, i));
                }
                Reader.Close();
            }
            index++;
        }

        if (document.PageNumber == 0)
        {
            document.Close();
            return;
        }
        document.Close();
        string SalesID = SALESID.Text;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + SalesID + ".pdf");
    }
```

Comment: Probably you could check whether you have anything to merge beforehand and only start merging of there is something to merge.

Comment: I probably will do that in case I can't find a more elegant way to leave the merge method

Answer (score 5):

In the old days, iText didn't throw an exception when you created a document and "forgot" to add any content. This resulted in a document with a single, blank page. This was considered a bug: people didn't like single-page, empty documents. Hence the design decision to throw an exception.

Something similar was done for `newPage()`. A new page can be triggered explicitly (when you add `document.newPage()` in your code) or implicitly (when the end of a page is reached). In the old days, this often resulted in unwanted blank pages. Hence the decision to ignore `newPage()` in case the current page is empty.

Suppose you have this:

```
document.newPage();
document.newPage();
```

One may expect that two new pages are created. That's not true. We've made a design decision to ignore the second `document.newPage()` because no content was added after the first `document.newPage()`.

This brings us to the question: what if we want to insert a blank page? Or, in your case: what if it's OK to create a document with nothing more than a single blank page?

In that case, we have to tell iText that the current page shouldn't be treated as an empty page. You can do so by introducing the following line:

```
writer.setPageEmpty(false);
```

Now the current page will be fooled into thinking that it has some content, even though it may be blank.

Adding this line to your code will avoid the **The document has no pages** exception and solve your problem of streams not being closed.

Take a look at the [NewPage](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#231-newpage.java) example if you want to experiment with the `setPageEmpty()` method.

Comment: Nice explanation, but in my case where I'm using PDFCopy how do I tell iText to stay cool about the lack of content. Anyway, I do not need the PDF to be created (see code: if document.PageNumber = 0). I will just advise the user that no valid PDF document had been selected and then quit the method. Martin

Answer (score 2):

You can add an empty page before closing the document, or catch the exception and ignore it.

Comment: Nice answer, but not quite complete. I've added a more elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still interested in a solution, or may be someone else.
I had exactly the same issue and I workaround-ed it by:
Declaring a boolean to figure out if at least one page have been added and before closing the document I referred on it.
If no pages have been copied, I add a new page in the document thanks to the AddPages method, with a rectangle as parameter. I did not find a simplest way to add a page.

So the code should be as bellow (with possibly some syntax errors as I'm not familiar with C#):

```
private void MergePDFs()
{
    DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
    DataView view = (DataView)SourceCertCockpit.Select(args);

    System.Data.DataTable table = view.ToTable();
    List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();

    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, Response.OutputStream);
    document.Open();

    int index = 0;
    foreach (DataRow myRow in table.Rows)
    {
        if (ListadoCertificadosCockpit.Rows[index].Cells[14].Text == "0")
        {
            PdfReader Reader = new PdfReader(Convert.ToString(myRow[0]));
            Chapter Chapter = new Chapter(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(myRow[1])), 0);
            Chapter.NumberDepth = 0;
            iTextSharp.text.Section Section = Chapter.AddSection(Convert.ToString(myRow[10]), 0);
            Section.NumberDepth = 0;
            iTextSharp.text.Section SubSection = Section.AddSection(Convert.ToString(myRow[7]), 0);
            SubSection.NumberDepth = 0;
            document.Add(Chapter);
            readerList.Add(Reader);
            bool AtLeastOnePage = false;
            for (int i = 1; i <= Reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(Reader, i));
                 AtLeastOnePage = true;
            }
            Reader.Close();
        }
        index++;
    }

     if (AtLeastOnePage)
        {
            document.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10);
            copy.AddPage(rec, 1);
            document.Close();
            return false;
        }
    string SalesID = SALESID.Text;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + SalesID + ".pdf");
}
```